# Meteor.http.post request for bitbucket

Tags: curl, meteor

I have to create issues in bitbucket and I use curl for that as:

```
curl --user {accountname}:{password} https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories/{accountname}/{repo_slug}/issues/ --data "title=some title"
```

but I cannot figure out how do I send the request in Meteor.http.post , as when I pass it as

```
    Meteor.http.post(https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories/{accountname}/{repo_slug}/issues/, {auth: {accountname}:{password}, data: "title=some title"}, function(error,result){
      console.log(result);
    });
```

I get error as

```
Error: failed [400] <ul class="errorlist"><li>title<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Please point me on the right direction as how  I can write the code of curl in meteor format.

Answer (score 0):

Try call:

```
   Meteor.http.post(https://bitbucket.org/.../,{auth: {accountname}:{password}, 
     data: {title: "some title"}, function(error,result){
      console.log(result);
   });
```

I think you incorrect setup `data` field.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it should be

```
Meteor.http.post('https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories/{accountname}/{repo_slug}/issues/', {auth: {accountname}:{password}, data: "title=some title"}, function(error,result){
  console.log(result);
});
```